# Progamatically Open The WPF Application From The System Tray

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls, system-tray

I have one application in the WPF that's by default running in the system tray.

I have one scenario in which the user can be confused.

- The application is running in the system tray
- Now, User tries to open the same application by searching the application name in the windows progeam search.
- In this case, The user will not get any acknowledge.

This is my code of `Global.cs` file. This code having condition for the application if its already running in the system tray or not .

```
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\" + appGuid))
{
    if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Now, What I want to do is, I want to open the application in the window mode when the user is casing above scenario. I have tried the below code which opens the window of the app, But, The system tray is now having two icons of the same application.

```
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\" + appGuid))
{
    if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Guide me the ways to open the application in the window mode if there is already instance in the system tray. Or help me to remove duplicate icons/instance from the system tray.

Comment: In the proposed duplicate, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522305/7444103) first -- If you tagged this `winforms` because you're using NotifyIcon, then you should add this detail to the question, possibly explaining how the functionality is implemented (e.g., WinForms Form, Console, message-only window etc.) -- You could also see [wpf-notifyicon - GitHub](https://github.com/hardcodet/wpf-notifyicon)